# OpenAL output sound 5.1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, openal, surround

In my project I'm using OpenAl, the 3d effect works fine, but only with the left/right speakers..
my pc have a 5.1 system, so 2 rear speakers, 2 front, 1 head and 1 subwoofer.

in windows is right configured, so if I see a movie or play a game that support a surround system, the sound exits from all the 6 speakers, but in my project not, only 2, like a song or a standard windows sound..

how I need to configure OpenAl to use 5.1 speakers?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the OpenAL programmer's guide from creative labs there is a section on multi-channel buffers on page 140.  The guide is found [here](http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/Documentation/OpenAL_Programmers_Guide.pdf).   This is an extension to OpenAL as you can see on page 131.

Comment: thanks, but I have a single channel soundwave, to let to manage the 3d sound.. not a 5.1 file to reproduce